# angularjs search and ignore spanish characters

Tags: angularjs

I'm adding a simple sort on a page. The idea is to search products. These products are written in spanish language and has accents. For example: 'Jamón'.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <label>Search</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="q"/>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="product in products_filtered = (category.products | filter:q | orderBy:'name')">
           ....
</div>
```

The only problem i have is that you have to type in "Jamón" in order to find the product "Jamón". What I want is to be more flexible, if the user types in "Jamon", the results must include "Jamón".

How can i search with angular filters and forget about accents? Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to create a filter function (or a full filter). This is the simplest thing that could possibly work:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:ignoreAccents">{{ name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    function removeAccents(value) {
        return value
            .replace(/á/g, 'a')            
            .replace(/é/g, 'e')
            .replace(/í/g, 'i')
            .replace(/ó/g, 'o')
            .replace(/ú/g, 'u');
    }

    $scope.ignoreAccents = function(item) {               
        if (!$scope.search) return true;       

        var text = removeAccents(item.toLowerCase())
        var search = removeAccents($scope.search.toLowerCase());
        return text.indexOf(search) > -1;
    };

    $scope.names = ['Jamón', 'Andrés', 'Cristián', 'Fernán', 'Raúl', 'Agustín'];
};
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gFGFN/1/).

Please notice that this only works for **arrays of strings**. If you want to filter a list of objects (and search in every property of every object, like Angular does) you'll have to enhance the filter function. I think this example should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has a neat function for this, called `localeCompare`, where you can specify `sensitivity = base`, an option that makes it treat `á` and `a` as equivalent, [but it is not widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2FlocaleCompare#Browser_Compatibility). I think your only option is to create a filter function wherein you normalise both strings manually (replacing `ó` with `o` and so on) and compare the results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly enhanced version (not counting the extra foreign characters it searches for, of course) of the above. I put it straight into my controller and it allowed me to search all the data that I wanted to search. Thanks Bernardo for your input into this!

Hope it helps somebody out.

```
 function removeAccents(value) {
    return value
         .replace(/á/g, 'a') 
         .replace(/â/g, 'a')            
         .replace(/é/g, 'e')
         .replace(/è/g, 'e') 
         .replace(/ê/g, 'e')
         .replace(/í/g, 'i')
         .replace(/ï/g, 'i')
         .replace(/ì/g, 'i')
         .replace(/ó/g, 'o')
         .replace(/ô/g, 'o')
         .replace(/ú/g, 'u')
         .replace(/ü/g, 'u')
         .replace(/ç/g, 'c')
         .replace(/ß/g, 's');
}

$scope.ignoreAccents = function (item) {
if ($scope.search) {
var search = removeAccents($scope.search).toLowerCase();
var find = removeAccents(item.name + ' ' + item.description+ ' ' + item.producer+ ' ' +        item.region).toLowerCase();
return find.indexOf(search) > -1;
}
return true;
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 'sharp s' supposed to be replaced with 'ss'? Or even 'sz' in parts of Austria.

Answer (score 2):

The method, proposed by @Michael Benford has a big disadvantage: it is a stateful filter. This practice is [strongly discouraged by angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). Plus, the method doesn’t work with deep arrays and objects.

I prefer to extend the standard angular filter:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: search : searchFn">{{ person.names }} {{ person.surnames }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.people = [{names: 'Jose', surnames: 'Benítez'}, {names: 'José María', surnames: 'Núñez Rico'}, {names: 'Rodrigo', surnames: 'Núñez'}];

        $scope.searchFn = function(actual, expected) {
            if (angular.isObject(actual)) return false;
            function removeAccents(value) {
                return value.toString().replace(/á/g, 'a').replace(/é/g, 'e').replace(/í/g, 'i').replace(/ó/g, 'o').replace(/ú/g, 'u').replace(/ñ/g, 'n');
            }
            actual = removeAccents(angular.lowercase('' + actual));
            expected = removeAccents(angular.lowercase('' + expected));

            return actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](http://www.criticaldevelopers.com/post/angularjs-search-and-ignore-accents-characters-filter) for solutions to filter a list of objects and search keywords in every property of every object. It also maintain angular like search and also search with/ without accent characters.

Following is the filter definition:-

```
                // ignore accents filter
            $scope.ignoreAccents = function (item) {
                if (!$scope.search) return true;
                var objects = [];
                var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(item);
                var parsejson = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
                var searchterm = $scope.search.replace(/[!#$%&'()*+,-./:;?@[\\\]_`{|}~]/g, '');    // skip replace if not required (it removes special characters)
                objects = getNoOfResults(parsejson, searchterm);
                return objects.length > 0;
            };
```