# Filtering special characters in ng-repeat with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to get the same result when I search Éric or Eric in an object. But I can't get Eric if I type "Éric" (Like it works with mySQL)

with something like this:

Object : { idEmployee=12710, firstName ="Eric", lastName="Tremblay", more...}

```
<input type="text" ng-model="modelFilter">
<table>
    <tr ng:repeat="friend in friends | filter:modelFilter">
        <td>{{friend.firstName}} {{friend.lastName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs search and ignore spanish characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164671/angularjs-search-and-ignore-spanish-characters)

Comment: the possible duplicate does not explain how to filter an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there exists no built-in method to convert text from "Éric" to "Eric", so you should manually create a simple function which replaces special characters with their standard equivalents. Then, create a method for replacement in your controller:

```
$scope.modelFilterNormalized = function(){
    if($scope.modelFilter)
        return $scope.modelFilter.replace('É','E').replace(/* ... */);
    else return '';
};
```

...and use it instead of `modelFilter`:

```
<tr ng:repeat="friend in friends | filter:modelFilterNormalized()">
```