# AngularJs search and ignoring diacritics

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

My idea is to have a list of words in which there are lots of diacritics or accents. And for example instead of writing *Róse* to have *Róse* I'd like to write *Rose* and have *Róse* in results.
First of all I googled for it, [here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164671/angularjs-search-and-ignore-spanish-characters) the problem was partially solved.

But what if I have array like this, [check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFGFN/13/):

```
     $scope.names = [{name: 'Jamón', surname: 'Géroux'},
    {name: 'Andrés', surname: 'Guérin'},
    {name: 'Cristián', surname: 'Róse'},
    {name: 'Fernán', surname:'Raúlien'}];
    };
```

Then the solution doesn't work: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFGFN/14/).
And what if I had, for example, custom filter for highlight:

```
     <td ng-bind-html="name.name | highlight:search.$"></td>
```

I've fount out, that all examples here https://builtwith.angularjs.org have the same problem with diacritics/accents. And only one website there http://illicoweb.videotron.com uses "simple technics" with JavaScript function and str.replace.

Any ideas on really simple and fast solution? Without storing two tables with diacritics/accents and without it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFGFN/16/) with my modifications to your filter. I've simply modified the filter to search the full name rather than just the first name as demonstrated:

```
$scope.ignoreAccents = function(item) {               
    if (!$scope.search)
        return true;

    var fullName = item.name + ' ' + item.surname;
    var text = removeAccents(fullName.toLowerCase());
    var search = removeAccents($scope.search.toLowerCase());
    return text.indexOf(search) > -1;
};
```

This approach should hopefully negate any need for two separate tables.

Comment: But I have a little question: what if I have ng-model with $ sign, like:     `<input type="text" ng-model="search.$">` — this is to avoid in input "[object Object] if I have an additional input like: `<input type="text" ng-model="search.name">` — how is it possible to modify this function? I tried to add $ sign somewhere but it didn't work.